# How to make PHPUnit fail on risky tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want PHPUnit to **fail** if one or more test is considered as risky. Actually:

```
PHPUnit 5.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..RRR..                                                         7 / 7 (100%)

Time: 2.83 seconds, Memory: 26.00Mb

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 7, Assertions: 137, Risky: 3.
```

It says "OK, but incomplete", so my tests did not fail (and can be shipped in case of continous delivery). Is there any way to have a "fail" status? I want my test global status considered as failed on risky test, don't know if it's possible.

Comment: agreed, this is very annoying because earlier versions DID fail on risky tests when in strict mode (or at least when output was generated by a test)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `--stop-on-risky` option that can be enabled from the command line or configured in the `phpunit.xml`.

The problem with this is that the run process wont execute all the tests. I'm not aware of a direct way of considering risky tests as failed.

The behaviour you want to obtain was proposed but not accepted, so don't expect to be implemented:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1612

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `--fail-on-risky` flag when calling the PHPUnit executable, or set the `failOnRisky="true"` attribute to the `<phpunit>` element in phpunit.xml.

In contrary to `--stop-on-risky`/`stopOnRisky="true"` this will not stop the test suite when PHPUnit encounters a risky test, but it will make PHPUnit exit with a non-zero status code, as it would when one of the tests fails.